# C++ string char array

Tags: c++, string, char

I am C++ beginner. I have a code as below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
   char sym[] = "Audi.Despo";
   //string sym ("Audi.Despo");
    string rs(sym);
    //cout << rs << endl;
    rs = string(sym,4);

 cout << rs;

    return 0;
}
```

If the variable sym is a char array the final output of the string variable is
Audi

but if the same variable sym is a string the final output is .Despo (the suffix is printed)

Whats the explanation.

Looks like the line

```
rs = string(sym,4);
```

changes its behaviour if its input is a char [] or a string.

Comment: See constructor documentation for `string` at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's just the different implementations of two of the constructor overloads:

```
string ( const string& str, size_t pos, size_t n = npos );
```

> Content is initialized to a copy of a substring of str. **The substring is the portion of str that begins at the character position pos and takes up to n characters** (it takes less than n if the end of str is reached before).

```
string ( const char * s, size_t n );
```

> Content is initialized to a copy of the string formed by **the first n characters in the array of characters pointed by s**.

Answer (score 0):

```
string ( const string& str, size_t pos, size_t n = npos );
```

Second argument in std::string's constructor is starting position of substring that is used to initialize content.

Answer (score 0):

When you say:

`rs=string(sym, 4);`

What you are doing is saying, "build me a `std::string` object, and I (the programmer) will help you (the program) do that by giving you this character array and a number."  The code behind `std::string` class knows that in that instance, where it is given a character array and an integer, that it should take the number of characters indicated from the character array and construct a `std::string` using that content.

When you say:

`string rs2=string(rs, 4);`

What you are now doing is saying, "build me a `std::string` object, and I will help you do that by giving you this *already existing* `std::string` object and a number."  The `std::string` class does something completely different in this case.  When it receives those two arguments, it instead uses the number as place to *start* reading from the provided `std::string`.

These two different cases are two different **constructors** for the `std::string` class--they provide two different ways to build a `std:string` object based on the information you have available.  You can easily make the second example work like the first by changing it to this form:

`string rs2=string(rs, 0, 4);`

Now you are telling it "initialize this new `std::string` (called `rs2`) by taking characters from the other `std::string` `rs`.  I want you to start at the character at index 0 (so, the first) and take 4 characters after that--if they exist."

It is important to know, before you construct an object of a class, how the constructors behave.  You can find documentation on all of the `std::string` constructors in many places online with some searches.

**Author's note:**  It is noted that many other things are happening in this example (for example, the assignment operator) and many issues are glossed over, but given the self-stated beginner nature of this question, I felt it best to keep it high level.